# update query the values are not being updated

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have two tables called dbo.RptSrc_ARDetail  and rptdata_monthly.dbo.rpt_dat_ARDetail.
 I am trying to update a field called arbucket with a field from rptdata_monthly.dbo.rpt_dat_ARDetail called transagebucket.
I Am not getting any errors but the value in the field for arbucket is not changing. 
Can someone point me in the right direction?

```
UPDATE dbo.RptSrc_ARDetail 
SET arbucket = dat.transagebucket
FROM dbo.RptSrc_ARDetail rpt
INNER JOIN rptdata_monthly.dbo.rpt_dat_ARDetail dat ON dat.uci = rpt.uci AN   dat.reportmonth = rpt.monasdt
AND dat.AID = rpt.AID AND dat.EID = rpt.EID AND dat.SLID = rpt.SLID AND dat.PatName =   rpt.PatName AND dat.AcctNu = rpt.AcctNu
WHERE dat.uci = 'BFP' and dat.reportmonth = '7/1/2013'
```

Comment: The most likely reason is that the join and/or where clause aren't being satisfied - what happens when you turn it into a SELECT query?

Comment: What is `dat.reportmonth`'s data type ?

Comment: I removed the dbo from the table name and it worked. Thanks Neville

Comment: You should replace `dbo.` with the actual schema the table is in, rather than just removing the `dbo.` prefix. Now the query works for you but it might not work for someone else.

Comment: Data did go into the RptSrc_ARDetail it wasnt the correct data. I have another field called dos that is a date. So how would I add an if statement so for example dos=7/15/2013 than agebucket = 0. I only need the month and year not the day.